# Neural Network Continuous tanh-Sigmoid Activation Function and Random Weights

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, neural-network

I really need help implementing a continuous tanh-sigmoid activation function in a very basic neural network. If you could give a basic example that would be great, but if you could change it in my [source code](http://jsfiddle.net/EXvXB/) I would be extremely grateful! Also, what range should the random weights be initiated with (i.e. what range)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The weight range depends on what input data range you have. In some implementations the weights can also be negative.

For possible Sigmoid functions, check here (tanh is not the only possibility):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function

Tip: You can typically compute the NN with matrix multiplications.

http://www.dtreg.com/mlfn.htm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_network

P.S.: probably not a good idea to do this in JavaScript.

---

you can either implement it via exp(x) , See: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathfunc.htm

```
          sinh(x)    exp(x) - exp(-x)     exp(2x) - 1
tanh(x) = ------- = ------------------ = -------------
          cosh(x)    exp(x) + exp(-x)     exp(2x) + 1
```

that gives you:

```
function tanh(x) {
   e = Math.exp(2*x);
   return (e - 1) / (e + 1) ;
};
```

another solution is to store a table with the tanh function values in an array, and define a JavaScript function which interpolates the tanh values for x based on the tanh values stored in the array

---

typically people don't want [-inf...+inf] as the range of the input values, and don't want [-1...+1] as the range of output values -- therefore you might need a different sigmoid function!

you need to take the expected range of input values, and the expected range of output values, and use those to shift the actual sigmoid function, the weight-ranges and the value of the threshhold.

a threshhold of 0.7 or larger is typically used. You need to experiment with that.

Comment: Yes, I know which function I need to use, but how do you actually implement it? What do you do with the value returned? What do you compare it against?

Comment: For my situation tanh and javascript is a must, bear with me :) But what I am really interested in is what it would look like in code.

Comment: O.K., you are one step away from answering my question :D Now that we have the value, what do you compare it against to determine whether or not to "activate" the neuron?

Comment: that's up to you - you can play around with it... but as tanh(x) is between -1 .. +1 , you probably want to compare it against |x| > 0.7 or something larger.

Comment: @Conner Ruhl: When you use tanh as activation function the output of the neuron is  continuous. Use a simple threshold to "toggle" output between 0/1 if you want ONLY binary output! That is, a neuron with tanh as activation function is always "active" in a sense...

Comment: @Tilo: Why should you limit yourself to weights (0,1)? That will give you trouble... Also, just to clarify, in NN terminology, THE sigmoid function is usually 1/(1+e^-cx). Also, tanh will give output on range (-1,1), never equal to -1 or 1!

Answer (score 0):

```
this.output = 2 / (1 + Math.exp(-2 * input)) - 1;
```

Comment: That dosen't seem to be the function I want to use (http://annet.eeng.nuim.ie/intro/course/chpt3/sigmoid.shtml, under "Tan Sigmoid"). But once you have that value, what do you do with it?

Comment: Do a litte algebra and you will find that when c = 1, the function in your link is equal to the function I posted.  Or just [ask Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28exp%28n%29+-+exp%28-n%29%29+%2F+%28exp%28n%29+%2B+exp%28-n%29%29+%3D%3D+2+%2F+%281+%2B+exp%28-2+n%29%29+-+1).